# Could someone guide me how to refresh an iframe in svelte?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, svelte-3, svelte-component

Good morning, I have a question about how to implement the metabase software update in svelte so that the dashboard is updated every 15 minutes, if someone could guide me with that.

in the template I have an iframe for metabase, the url comes from an enpoint, I had the doubt of how to implement that iframe refresh every 10 or 15 min

```html
<script lang="ts">
    
    export let url = '';
    let metabaseInterval:any;
    
    function callRefersh(){
        window.location.reload();
    }

    metabaseInterval = ()  => {
       setInterval(() => {callRefersh},120000, console.log('ererer'))
    }

</script>


{#if metabaseInterval }
  <iframe src={url} frameborder="0" allowtransparency style="width:100%;height: calc(100vh + 15px);" title='dashboard'></iframe>
{/if}
```

Comment: What is the owner document of that `<script>` block, the page hosting the iframe, or the iframe itself?

Comment: I did not understand the question correctly, but what that iframe does is show a url of a metabase dashboard, it only does that, what I had doubts is how to refresh that dashboard in svelte, every 10 minutes.

Comment: the url variable comes from an enpoint is passed by props from another component so it is with export

Answer (score 1):

```
on:click{()=>{reloadHandler}} // this way too for calling on click
on:click{reloadHandler} //This way to call asap
const reloadHandler = () => {
           setTimeout(function () {
           url = '';
           url = oldURL;
           reloadHandler();
                                 }, 
                       10 * 60 * 1000);
                            }
```

Just call this function once and it will work forever.